# Tagging / Entity extraction using an entity list

Tags: tagging, entities, data-extraction

I'm looking for a good solution to extract entities from a text. 
In my case, entities are movie titles (so they could be quite long strings) and I have them stored in a database.

What could be a good way to do this ? Is there any already developed software to perform this kind of task ?

I've seen nltk, but what I need is way less complex: Given a (huge) list of strings, identify them in the input text.

Thanks!

Comment: I need sth like this,I think nobody want to help!